# Python Help! Code works, just needs a tweaking. RNG from 0-99, self-changing every 2 seconds

Tags: python, loops, random, while-loop, numbers

First time coding. I found part of an RNG code online. I'm trying to get it to change to a new random number every 2 seconds with-out me clicking on it. I know it's probably something to do with "while" or "after". But I just can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be great! Here's the code I have so far:

```
    from tkinter import Tk, Label, StringVar
    import random 
    
    root = Tk()
    root.title('RNG')
    root.configure(background='black')
    tout = StringVar()
    label = Label(root, textvariable=tout, font=('TkDefaultFont', 99), bg='black')
    label.pack()
    
    def _quit():
        root.quit()
        root.destroy()
    
    def gen_rand():
        randvar = random.randint(0,99)
        tout.set(randvar)
        if randvar < 25:
           label.config(fg='red')
        elif randvar < 50:
           label.config(fg='orange')
        elif randvar < 75:
           label.config(fg='yellow')
        else:
            label.config(fg='green')
    
    gen_rand()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What you're looking for is `root.after()`.  You can have Tkinter call a callback after 2 seconds elapsed.  The function can then call it again to arrange another call for later.

Comment: I replaced the "gen_rand()" thats at the end with:   root.after(2000, gen_rand). When I run it now, it does the 2 second delay for the very first number but then doesn't change.

Comment: You probably need to do something to get the control to repaint itself after you've updated the property.  Unfortunately I don't know how that's done in Tk.

Comment: Don't change the existing `gen_rand()`.  Add `root.after(2000,gen_rand)` additionallly at the end of the `gen_rand` function so it gets scheduled to be called again.  The existing `gen_rand()` call just kicks off the chain.

Comment: You're the man Mark Tolonen! Works perfectly! I knew it had to be something so damn easy. Thank you a lot man.

Comment: @TimRoberts had the answer. I just clarified. I didn’t know about `root.after`.

Comment: Well thank you Tim. And thank you everyone for your help.